# reactjs compilation error 'e' is undefined no-undef in specific scenario

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am trying to play around with different ways of writing a javascript function to log user entry in a text box .
The following pieces of code work fine :
option1: ( works fine )

```
import React from "react";
class PlayMaster1 extends React.Component{

handleComponent(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleComponent}/>
            <h3>hello</h3>
        </div>

    )
}
}
export default PlayMaster1;
```

option 2 ( works fine using arrow functions ) :

```
import React from "react";
class PlayMaster1 extends React.Component{

handleComponent(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.handleComponent(e)}/>
            <h3>hello</h3>
        </div>

    )
}
}
export default PlayMaster1;
```

**EDIT1: option 3 was incorrect and deleted the same**

Option 4 - does not work -

```
import React from "react";
class PlayMaster1 extends React.Component{

handleComponent(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleComponent(e)}/>
            <h3>hello</h3>
        </div>

    )
}
}
export default PlayMaster1;
```

So why is the 'event' undefined in option 4 ? why does that become implicitly available in all other cases ?

Comment: #3 and 4 are identical, did you copy #3 incorrectly?

Comment: my bad will edit and remove #3 and reword the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onChange={this.handleComponent}
```

This means "pass `this.handleComponent` into the onChange prop". Simple and legal.

```
onChange={(e) => this.handleComponent(e)}
```

This means "make a new function with the text `(e) => this.handleComponent(e)`, and pass it into the onChange prop". A bit more complicated, but everythings fine here too.

```
onChange={this.handleComponent(e)}
```

This means "immediately call `this.handleComponent`, passing in `e`. Whatever is returned by handleComponent, pass that into the onChange prop". There is no variable named `e` in your render method, so this can't be done. It's also almost certainly not what you want to do, since handleComponent looks like a function that is designed to run when the change event happens, not when render happens.

Comment: what I am still not clear is why in option1 the event is available to the called function without it being passed , in option 2 we get a handle to the event  and so I was thinking that similarly the event would be available in option 4 ?

Comment: `what I am still not clear is why in option1 the event is available to the called function without it being passed` The event is passed, just not by you. The browser is the one that eventually calls your function, and it will pass in the event object when it does so. `so I was thinking that similarly the event would be available in option 4` in number 4, you are calling the function yourself. You need to pass the function, not call it, and let the browser call it when the event occurs.